# Find whether a child node has a particular class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table row:

```
<tr>
   <td class>1</td>
   <td class="check">2</td>
   <td class>3</td>
</tr>
```

I have a variable x which access the above code, like so `x.parentElement`.

How can I find out which column `<td>` tag (the first, the second or the third) contains the class `check`?

Comment: What do you have to do with the <td> which has check class?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's just:

```
$(x.parentElement).find('.check').text();
```

assuming that `x.parentElement` is a DOM element.  Here, we find the first child of that DOM element that has the `"check"` class and return its text data.

Comment: It's quite ok.. What makes you assume he wants `.check` `text()`? 
I'm voting up anyway.

Comment: @enapupe -- Well, other than the class check, there's no other way to tell the `<td>` elements apart.  Of course, if he wants the element to manipulate further, then he shouldn't use `.text` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $('td').parent();
var hit = x.children().filter('.check');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vKu9/15/

Comment: There is no need for $.each